# Script works without sudo, fails with sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, scp, sftp

When I launch this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -v
sshpass -p '<pypasswd>' scp blah.img root@myip:/home/user/blah.img
exit 0
```

with

```
./script.sh
```

or

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

it works.

But when I do

```
nohup sudo ./script.sh &
```

it fails (nothing is uploaded, and I once got a authentification error, that I cannot reproduce anymore). **Why?**

---

Note: I usually use `nohup sudo ./script.sh &` for some other scripts and it usually works perfectly.

Note 2: I really need `sudo` because there are other things in my script that need sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there's no `myip` recorded in `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`.  Please try once `sudo ssh root@myip` interactively before running that script.

Alternatively, you can disable host key checking:

```
#!/bin/bash -v
sshpass -p '<pypasswd>' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no blah.img root@myip:/home/user/blah.img
exit 0
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works!

Comment: I think `exit $?` is much better than `exit 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your root user doesn't have the same private keys that you are using when not running as root. Therefore, as root, you cannot copy the material.

Try copying adding `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` (or some other private key you are using to connect to `myip`).

Alternatively let the `sudo` do the other things, and change back to the "normal" user in the script explicitly before doing the copy.